# Code Coverage for OpportunityHistory For Loop in Batch Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, opportunity-history

How to get coverage for this

**Batch Class :**

```
    ----
    --- other code
    ---
    for(Task objTask : listTask){
      for(OpportunityHistory obj : listOppHistory){    
          if(objTask.CreatedDate > obj.CreatedDate){   *** CODE NEED COVERAGE
             ------                                    *** CODE NEED COVERAGE
             ------ Code Need coverage                 ****** CODE NEED COVERAGE 
             -------                                   ***CODE NEED COVERAGE
          }                                            ***CODE NEED COVERAGE
      }
   }
```

**TEST Class :**

- Inserted an Opportunity
- Changed "StageName" of an Opprtunity and Updated the same Opportunity again.

  `//Insert Opportunity
  Opportunity objOpp = new Opportunity();
  objOpp.Name='Test Opp';
  objOpp.AccountId=objAcc.id;
  objOpp.CloseDate = Date.Today()+5;
  objOpp.StageName='Prospecting';
  insert objOpp;

  //Upadate Opportunity
  objOpp.CloseDate = Date.Today()+3;
  update objOpp;`
- Still no Coverage ?

Any Suggestions ! Guidelines ! Answers !! Point_To_Documents ?

Comment: There are no way to create history records in SF unfortunately. to cover it, I would like to suggest you to do next script.
**if (Test.isRunningTest()){ listOppHistory = <generate some history data>}**
And even that is bad, cause you can not set certain fields for that records on creation because they are read only. I would recommend you to move that logic to separate method, that takes as parameter list of custom objects, that you create from history records, and cover that method

Comment: Will you please elaborate - How should I include If(test.isRunningTest()){} in my code .

Answer (score 3):

If you are really determined to cover this set of code, you'll need to abstract in your PROD code to how you fetch the history data to an interface.

I discuss this in a [related answer to how to mock data otherwise unmockable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102720/2602)

In essence:

- Prod class uses a PROD implementation of an interface to return via SOQL the histories
- Test Class implements the interface by returning a list of sobjects constructed using JSON.deserialize, this will let you create the fields you need
- Test class replaces the variable in the PROD class that defines which interface to use at runtime with the test class's implementation of the interface. This replacement is done before exercising any PROD methods (i.e.immediately after constructing the PROD class).

Thus, when the PROD class runs in PROD context, the SObjects are fetched using SOQL, when the PROD class runs in TEST context, the SObjects are fetched from a list the testmethod generates.

The approach gives you flexibility in creating various combinations of test sobjects for different use cases

Comment: OMG! This is so clever way of creating the records we need. But like you mentioned it becomes complex if we have to deal with relationships. Note: I just tested the code in my org with the example you mentioned and it works fine. Thanks for sharing with us.

Comment: @SalesforceSteps - Can you mark as accepted please since it seems it worked for your situation